# What is the proper way to identify a font for .spacemacs file?

Tags: spacemacs, fonts, install, default

Spacemacs isn't finding my Source Code Pro font files, and I think it's a naming issue. I have the fonts installed and in the font cache,

```
/usr/local/share$ fc-list : file | grep source
```

Returns:

```
/usr/share/fonts/adobe-source-code-pro/SourceCodePro-Bold.otf: 
/usr/share/fonts/adobe-source-code-pro/SourceCodePro-It.otf: 
/usr/share/fonts/adobe-source-code-pro/SourceCodePro-BlackIt.otf: 
/usr/share/fonts/adobe-source-code-pro/SourceCodePro-BoldIt.otf: 
/usr/share/fonts/adobe-source-code-pro/SourceCodePro-Medium.otf: 
/usr/share/fonts/adobe-source-code-pro/SourceCodePro-ExtraLight.otf: 
/usr/share/fonts/adobe-source-code-pro/SourceCodePro-LightIt.otf: 
/usr/share/fonts/adobe-source-code-pro/SourceCodePro-Semibold.otf: 
/usr/share/fonts/adobe-source-code-pro/SourceCodePro-MediumIt.otf: 
/usr/share/fonts/adobe-source-code-pro/SourceCodePro-Black.otf: 
/usr/share/fonts/adobe-source-code-pro/SourceCodePro-Light.otf: 
/usr/share/fonts/adobe-source-code-pro/SourceCodePro-SemiboldIt.otf: 
/usr/share/fonts/adobe-source-code-pro/SourceCodePro-ExtraLightIt.otf: 
/usr/share/fonts/adobe-source-code-pro/SourceCodePro-Regular.otf:
```

But every time I load up spacemacs it returns the error:

```
Cannot find any of the specified fonts (adobe-source-code-pro)! Font settings
  may not be correct.
```

In my .spacemacs file, I have

```
dotspacemacs-default-font '("adobe-source-code-pro"
                               :size 13
                               :weight normal
                               :width normal
                               :powerline-scale 1.1)
```

What can I change so that spacemacs will correctly find my fonts?

Comment: Cross posted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44332322/what-is-the-proper-way-to-identify-a-font-for-spacemacs-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wasn't a naming issue, it was a dependency issue possibly related to me using Red Hat Fedora. I was missing the liboft-dev library emacs needs to read .otf files, which are separate from the liboft libraries in Red Hat.

When looking at the ./configuration output, it stated:

```
Does Emacs use -lfreetype?                              no
Does Emacs use -lm17n-flt?                              no
Does Emacs use -lotf?                                   no
Does Emacs use -lxft?                                   no
```

After adding the dependency and re-making, the fonts are correctly recognized under the name "Source Code Pro", which is most likely defined in the .otf file, despite it having a different name.

My .spacemacs file now reads

```
dotspacemacs-default-font '("adobe-source-code-pro"
                               :size 13
                               :weight normal
                               :width normal
                               :powerline-scale 1.1)
```

and all the errors are gone. Hope this fixes your problem too!

Comment: What gave you ./configuration output? How did you "add the dependency," and then "re-make?"